I can only access a site(via iframe) if I have opened it before. How do I fix it?
I have a very simple HTML. When I try to open it, it throws a 403 error.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Embed</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <object data="https://www.website_to_open.com/" class="container" type="text/html"> Alternative Content </object>
</body>
</html>

I assume the error has something to do with cookies because if I open website_to_open.com first and then open my HTML, it works fine.

If it does have to do with cookies, then there probably isn't much you can do. You can not set cookies for other sites, and if that site only sets the necessary cookie, when it somehow detects that it was loaded "outside" of any frames - then that's what you'll have to do, in one form or another.

The owner of that other site probably wouldn't have implemented such a restriction, if they wanted you to be able to do this.

You need to configure the server to allow the page to be loaded into an iframe. If this is not your server, then you need to come to a business agreement with the site owner to allow your site to put their site in your iframe.

The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error response status code indicates that the server understood the request but refused to process it. This status is similar to 401, except that for 403 Forbidden responses, authenticating or re-authenticating makes no difference. The request failure is tied to application logic, such as insufficient permissions to a resource or action.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

